# Force Android Emulator to be slow

Tags: android, android-emulator

It's possible to force an Android Emulator to be slow?
I launch a Galaxy S3 image, but it behaves much faster than an real device.
I need a way to simulate a real device condition.

I'm working on improving my app perfomance and everything runs pretty fast on my notebook.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Android emulated device, such as your Galaxy S3 image, you can create or import a hardware profile and reduce RAM memory to slow down the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a device with fewer characteristics than the real to simulate a really slow device, you can select the Ram Memory and others characteristic of the device, you can custom your phone in the "New Hardware profile option" in your Android Virtual Device Manager.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRbDF.png

Comment: I actually did it, but it still works pretty fast. I can only reduce the RAM, but I can reduce the processor clock.

Comment: I understand, I just can think in use other emulator. Let me check a possible options list.